# Convert scala.collection.immutable list into clojure vector

Tags: scala, clojure, immutability

I want to convert scala.collection.immutalble list to clojure vector.
input: `#object[scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon 0xb4b9600 "List(172.16.133.57)"]`
output: `[172.16.133.57]`

Please help me with this. I have tried `seq`/`asJavaList` etc but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: please share your tryings and explain the problem that you have

Comment: Have you tried `vec` ? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec

Comment: Yep,
I have tried `vec`, but no luck.
@RameshMaharjan , I have mentioned my tryings. And question is pretty much clear, I just want to convert `scala.immutable.collection` to `clojure.lang.PersistentVector`.

Comment: HI Abhishek, do you have any solution for this ? I have same problem to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can .head and .tail functions of collections with loop recur can convert to vector

more info can be found here

https://github.com/npinnaka/process-array-elements/blob/master/src/process_array_elements/core.clj